# Lists into a string onto text file?

Tags: python

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
words = sentence.split()
position= [0]
myList = [] 

[myList.append(x) for x in words if x not in myList]
a =(" ".join(myList))
print (myList)
if words.count(i) <2:
    position.append(max(position) +1)
else:
    position.append(words.index(i) +1)

position.remove(0)

print (position)
words = str(words)
position = str(position)

file = open("recreated_positions","w")
file.write(a) 
file.write(position)
file.close()
```

This piece of code will put the positions of each word as a number and print the sentence on the python shell and textfile.

For example, if the sentence was *'I like english but I do not like maths'*.
The program would output

```
['i','like','english,'but','do','not','maths'] 
[1,2,3,4,1,5,6,2,7]
```

In the textfile, the program doesn't output the sentence in the same way it 
does above.

Any suggestions on how to make it do the same thing in the text file?

Comment: Fix formatting.

Comment: So what does it output in the textfile?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove duplicates from your list, then use `index` to get the position of an element:

```
sentence = raw_input("Please enter a sentence:")
words = sentence.split()

myList = []

for x in words:  
    if x not in myList:
        myList.append(x)

a = str(myList)

positions= [myList.index(word) + 1 for word in words]

print positions

file = open("recreated_positions","w")
file.write(a + '\n') 
file.write(str(positions))
file.close()
```

**Output**:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7]
```

Comment: Is this useful.